# if we want to make modification to running pods configuration, which is advisable whether to deployment or to pods?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

If we have some requirement to modify property of running pods, Which will be the recommeneded way and whats the reason.

I guess once a pod deployed as part of the deployment, we can modify the pods properties either by kubectl edit pod or by kubectl edit deploy.

Would like to understand is there any difference between these 2 actions. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the Deployment not the Pod.

**Why?**

The Deployment describe the desired state for your pods. The Deployment controller continuously watches for the Deployment object in a control loop. It reads the desired pod state from the Deployment specification and try to ensure the state in the cluster. So, if you edit the pod and change something, the Deployment controller will overwrite the change in next resync because your modification is not present in the Deployment specification.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part you *can't* edit the pods.  In the [API definition of a PodSpec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#PodSpec), the `containers` and `initContainers` fields are both described as "Cannot be updated."  Almost all of the interesting things in a Pod spec are in the Container sub-objects.

The corollary to this is that you can't "modify properties of running pods" for the most part; you can only delete and replace them with new pods with the properties you want.  If you edit the pod template in a deployment spec, Kubernetes will do exactly that.